# Sightseeing: Tollifer's Last Stand

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

The *Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls* achievement *Sightseeing* says to "complete all of the following events in Westmarch." There are sixteen events to complete in Westmarch Commons and Westmarch Heights.

The final piece of the puzzle for me is *Tollifer's Last Stand*. According to [this post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12506570745) on Blizzard's forums it is in Westmarch Commons. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CrgBr53CSV8) shows it being completed, but does not go into much detail.

I have performed a full clear of Westmarch Commons many times both in Adventure Mode and in Campaign Mode. I have seen every other event multiple times by now, but not this one. As the video advises I have been very diligent to keep my eyes peeled for doorways with the sparkly body and on the minimap for the dot. Nothing.

How do I complete this achievement? Do I need to be on a certain mode? Is it really super rare, or am I the victim of the RNG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has yet to be confirmed but the event does not seem to spawn in adventure mode (or at least not as often as it should). I've found it several time now in story mode so I advise you to try story mode. It's a rare spawn and there are no tricks to find this event, just luck.

Comment: There is a specific set piece that must appear in the map. The video linked in my question shows it at approximately 0:56. In addition, Tolifer's corpse must also spawn. The set piece is a rare tile to begin with, and the corpse also appears to be rare. This makes it double-rare. Almost a year after asking my question I was able to find a few videos and forum posts that corroborate your answer, although the rarity of Tolifer in adventure mode is still up for debate.